# Maximal subgroup of a direct product

Tags: group-theory

Suppose that $G = A \times B$. Let $M$ be a maximal subgroup of $A$. Then $M \times B$ is a maximal subgroup of $G$

So let $Q$ be a subgroup of $G$ such that $M \times B \leq Q < A \times B = G$.

I need to show that $Q \leq M \times B$. Consider the projection maps $\pi_A$ and $\pi_B$. Now $\pi_A( M \times B) = M \leq \pi_A(Q)$ and $\pi_B(M \times B) = B \leq \pi_B(Q)$. Since $M$ is maximal in $A$, we have that $M = \pi_A(Q)$ or $\pi_A(Q) = A$. If $\pi_A(Q) = A$. Can I say that $Q = A \times \pi_B(Q)$?. If this is the case then by the above arguments I have that $A \times B \leq A \times \pi_B(Q) = Q$. Hence $Q = A \times B =G$, contradicting our choice of $Q$. Thus $ M = \pi_A(Q)$, and so $Q \leq \pi_A(Q) \times \pi_B(Q) \leq M \times B$, and we are done.

My question is: If $\pi_A(Q) = A$, then can I assume that $Q = A \times \pi_B(Q)$?

Comment: If what  you have to prove is that $\;M\times B\;$ is actually maximal in  $\;B\;$, then your second line is odd... What *exactly* is the question here, anyway?

Comment: @DonAntonio, given $M$ maximal in $A$, I want to show that $M \times B$ is maximal in $A \times B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not generally the case that $\pi_A(Q)=A$ implies $Q\cong A\times \pi_B(Q)$ - for example if $B=A$ and $Q=\{(a,a)|a\in A\}$. You might be able to use $M\times B\le Q$ to get this result, but I don't know how you would do this without first showing $M\times B= Q$.

A different approach, is to suppose $Q>M\times B$ so there is some $(a,b)\in Q$ with $a\notin M$. We also have $(1,b)\in M\times B\le Q$ so $(a,1)\in Q$. Therefore as a subgroup of $Q$ you have $\langle M\times 1, (a,1)\rangle$. Now since $M$ is maximal in $A$ we have $\langle M\times 1, (a,1)\rangle=A\times 1$, so $Q=A\times B$.